# Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400024. error code in Qtspim

Tags: mips, qtspim

I have to convert this C code to Mips and I run the code on Qtspim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 1000; i++)
    sum = sum + i;
    printf("sum=%d", sum);

    return 0;

}
```

and my Mips code is

```
.data

.text

li $s1, 0
li $s2, 0
Loop:
    slt $t0, $s2, 1000
    beq $t0, $0, Exit
    add $s2, $s2, $s1
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    j Loop
Exit:


li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s2
```

please tell me what's wrong..

it says "attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400024

Comment: You haven't added any code to terminate the program (e.g. system call 10).

Comment: oh yeah I realized that and added it but it still shows the error message.

Comment: Well, you also haven't provided a `main` label for the simulator to use as an entry point into your program.

Comment: thx so I put "main:" at the beginning of the code but it's the same.

Comment: You probably didn't export the label using `.globl main`. I suggest you read the documentation for the simulator or look at some example programs.

Comment: #s1:i, t0:flag, s2:sum
 
 .data


 .text
 .globl main
main:

 li $s1, 0
 li $s2, 0
 Loop:
  slt $t0, $s1, 1000
  beq $t0, $0, Exit
  add $s2, $s2, $s1
  addi $s1, $s1, 1
  j Loop
 Exit:
 

 li $v0, 1
 move $a0, $s2
 syscall

Comment: so I put .global main and everything like an example code but It's the same..

Comment: I posted my new code in a new question. u can check it out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
sumnum: .asciiz "Sum: "
.text
main:

li $s1, 0 #for i
li $s2, 0 #for sum
li $s3, 1000 #for loop condition
Loop:
    
    beq $s1, $s3, Exit #loop
    add $s2, $s2, $s1 # adding
    addi $s1, $s1, 1 # increment for i
    j Loop
Exit:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sumnum      #print sum
    syscall
    
    move $a0, $s2    
    li $v0, 1     #print value for sum
    syscall     

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```